# Install xlsx and rJava on macOS Mavericks 10.9.5

Tags: java, r, macos, rjava

Its being a real nightmare to install rjava on my Mac.

My setup:

```
MacOS 10.9.5
Java: 7u71 (64 bits dowloaded from Oracle site)
R: R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
```

First, in the command line I ran the

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Then, I ran inside R:

```
install.packages('rJava')
```

The error in the end of the compiling is this:

```
JavaVM -F/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -llzma -lm -liconv -licuuc -licui18n
ld: library not found for -licuuc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libjri.jnilib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/JRI.jar] Error 2
make: *** [jri] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/Users/costa/Library/R/3.1/library/rJava’
```

I tried Java 8 and the Mac default java and also got the same error.

Ideias?

Comment: I believe I had to install the snow leopard build and it works fine

Comment: I tried that using this version: http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1573 but I could not install (my Mac is a 10.9.5)

Comment: `openxlsx` is a nice alternative that doesn't depend on Java. https://github.com/cran/openxlsx

Answer (score 4):

What I did (using macports R) as root (sudo bash):

- edit
  `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Makeconf`
  and change the line

  ```
  LIBS =  -llzma -lm -liconv -licuuc -licui18n
  ```

  to

  ```
  LIBS =  -llzma -lm -liconv
  ```
- install the original 1.6 Mac Java
- export
  `JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`
- run `R CMD javareconf`

Now you can start R and do a `install.packages("rJava")`. Using the 1.6 version of Java made sure that also RStudio can load the rJava package.

If you do not plan using RStudio, you can also use Java 1.8

Comment: worked for me just to change the flags in the `Makeconf`file! Also, you might need to run `R CMD javareconf` with `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on my computer (Mac OS 10.9.5, Java 1.8.0_11, R 3.1.1). Installing the newest Java JDK from Oracle (1.8.0_25) didn't solve the problem (yet). However, after updating Java, installing R 3.1.2 solved the problem for me. After running `install.packages("rJava")`, this works:

```
> library("rJava")
> .jinit() # this starts the JVM
> s <- .jnew("java/lang/String", "Hello World!")
> .jcall(s,"I","length")
[1] 12
```

Do note that updating the *JDK* is something different from the Java version in the GUI Java Control Panel, accessible through the System preferences. The latter is only the *JRE* for the internet browser plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I was actually able to avoid editing my environment completely by using the Mac binary to install rJava on my Macbook (running OSX Yosemite and R version 3.2.3). First, do the following in R to install rJava:

```
install.packages("rJava", type = "mac.binary")
```

Presumably independent of this, for some reason I couldn't install xlsx until I first installed the `xlsxjars` dependency. So do the following in R:

```
install.packages(c("xlsxjars", "xlsx"))
```

And with those two commands, xlsx appears to install just fine on a mac!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Then, in the R interpretor:

```
install.packages('rJava', type='source')
install.packages('xlsx', type='source')
```

Comment: I get compilation failed for rJava at this stage: install.packages('rJava', type='source')

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I'm using OS X Yosemite and initially had installed R through homebrew

I performed the following steps to fix it:

1. Closed all instances of R
2. In my terminal shell, ran `sudo R CMD javareconf`
3. Opened up R from my terminal and ran:

   `install_packages("rJava")`

   `install_packages("xlsx")`

Answer (score 0):

Using the old Java SE 6 I was able to get rJava compiled by running javareconf as follows:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home \
JAVA_CPPFLAGS=-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/ \
r CMD javareconf
```