# Install rJava on macOS Sierra 10.12.1: linker error licuuc

Tags: java, r, installation, rjava

I am trying to install rJava within R-Studio but the error

```
ld: library not found for -licuuc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libjri.jnilib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/JRI.jar] Error 2
make: *** [jri] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/Users/iMacLinda/Library/R/3.3/library/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
```

*R*

> version _ platform x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0 arch x86_64 os
>   darwin16.1.0 system x86_64, darwin16.1.0 status major 3 minor 3.2 year
>   2016 month 10 day 31 svn rev 71607 language R version.string R version
>   3.3.2 (2016-10-31) nickname Sincere Pumpkin Patch

**How can I fix this linker error?**

Comment: You should mention the OS X version and the version of R you are using. Otherwise it is a guess and an answer is impossible. See this [thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2016-February/011836.html) on the R-SIG-Mac mailinglist.

Comment: In addition: you don't seem to have library `icuuc`. I would first try to resolve that problem.

Comment: I am using macOS Sierra v 10.12.1 and as for R i have got the following

Comment: > version
               _      
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin16.1.0                
system         x86_64, darwin16.1.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.2                         
year           2016                        
month          10                          
day            31                 
svn rev        71607 
language       R 
version.string R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
nickname       Sincere Pumpkin Patch

Comment: I seem to have iccuc on my system but how do I get Rstudio to see it/opt/local/lib/libicuuc.55.1.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libicuuc.55.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libicuuc.a
/opt/local/lib/libicuuc.dylib

Comment: I have found this solution posted elsewhere. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28886808/5446956

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution elsewhere with MacPorts, steps 1-5 guided by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28886808/5446956) and steps 6 guided by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31039105/5446956).

1. As root (sudo bash), edit `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Makeconf` and change the line `LIBS = -llzma -lm -liconv -licuuc -licui18n` to `LIBS = -llzma -lm -liconv`
2. install the original 1.6 Mac Java
3. run `export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`
4. `R CMD javareconf`
5. Now you can start R and do `install.packages("rJava")`.
6. `sudo ln -f -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib`

Answer (score 1):

*There is a solution for this with Anaconda [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45134672/164148). The problem was with the path variable so perhaps this could solve the problem here as well. I outline the solution below about how it could be solved here.*

---

### **Clean up your path**

1. Check up your config settings

   ```
   R CMD config --ldflags
   -L/Users/osx/anaconda3/lib/R/lib -lR -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lm -liconv -licuuc -licui18n
   ```
2. Test this `mv ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile_backup`.
3. Restart your terminal.
4. Now the environment variables in R should be different

   ```
   $ R CMD config --ldflags
   -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -licucore -lm -liconv
   ```
5. Run the following

   ```
   sudo R CMD javareconf 
   Rscript -e 'install.packages("rJava", repos="http://rforge.net", type="source")'
   ```
6. If you was able to install rJava, the problem was in your path otherwise try alternative solutions.

**Alternative solution with Homebrew**

There is also a solution for this with Homebrew [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45134672/164148) where R is installed with `brew cask install r-app` and gcc had to be recompiled without a forenmp flag.