# trouble installing and loading rJava on mac El Capitan

Tags: r, installation, rjava

Have issue installing rJava, tried most troubleshooting steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755013/install-xlsx-and-rjava-on-mac) and doesn't work.

It's returning error

```
Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
 call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object     '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/    rJava.so':
```

I'm on latest ver of R/Rstudio and Mac El Capitan

I also tried this method 1 which didn't work

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Then, in the R interpreter:

```
install.packages('rJava', type='source')
install.packages('xlsx', type='source')
```

method 2

```
sudo ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

error returned ln: /usr/local/lib/libjvm.dylib: File exists

method 3
    install.packages("rJava", type = "binary")
error: tar: Failed to set default locale

to deal with default locale error

```
system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")
```

upon loading rJava, still same error:

```
image not found
```

So looks like it's installed but won't load

Comment: There are far more SO threads than that one: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5br%5d%20rjava%20macos

Comment: thanks for the reply, I actually tried many of them, nothing works so far

Comment: I've just written a short note on this and hope it is helpful: https://zhiyzuo.github.io/installation-rJava/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was rJava wont install in `RStudio` (`Version 1.0.136`). The following worked for me (`macOS Sierra version 10.12.6`) (found [here](https://gist.github.com/mmulvahill/ddd75eb352979cc922bae001505833cb)):

Step-1: Download and install `javaforosx.dmg` from [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US)

Step-2: Next, run the command from inside RStudio:

```
install.packages("rJava", type = 'source')
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution

Define path to R libraries, here R 3.4 version and open dir:

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib
```

Remove libjvm.dylib:

```
rm libjvm.dylib
```

Create link to libjvm.dylib from Java libraries, here jdk1.8.0_151 version:

```
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib libjvm.dylib
```

now go to R or RStudio and try:

```
library("rJava")
```

Comment: This method worked for me.  But I symlinked from the framework's /lib directory to the already symlinked `/usr/local/lib/libjvm`  with `ln -s /usr/local/lib/libjvm.dylib ./` rather than directly into tha java 8 directory.

Answer (score 4):

I did the same thing for java 9, it worked perfectly (macOS High Sierra), thanks:

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib
rm libjvm.dylib
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib libjvm.dylib
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had a lot of trouble with this and eventually found the following SO thread to be the most relevant: [rJava load error in RStudio/R after "upgrading" to OSX Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite)

Basically, starting from no installation of rJava, and starting in the terminal:

1. Form the sym link (note, the `-f` flag will overwirte existing links avoiding the error you encountered in "method 2".

`$ sudo ln -f -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib`

Then in RStudio:

2. Ensure `options('java.home')` isn't `NULL`, and set if necessary:

`options("java.home"="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre")`

3. Ensure the `JAVA_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables are set, and set if not:

`Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home')
Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/server')`

After this I was able to install and load the rJava package in RStudio with

```
install.packages('rJava')
library(rJava)
```

Comment: your solution doesn't work: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details: (...)

Comment: After step (1), rather than set environment variables to tune the path, you could set an additional symlink in the `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib` directory to the `/usr/local/lib/libjvm.dylib` file:  `ln -s /usr/local/lib/libjvm.dylib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried most of the recommendations on this site, but none worked. The only working solution for me was on this [Github site](https://github.com/MTFA/CohortEx/wiki/Run-rJava-with-RStudio-under-OSX-10.10,-10.11-(El-Capitan)-or-10.12-(Sierra)) site.

Hope this solves your issues.