# cannot install rJava on macOS Catalina 10.15.1

Tags: macos-catalina, rjava, r-xlsx

My mac system is macOS Catalina 10.15.1, and my R version is 3.6.1. When I try to install the rJava package on Rstudio using `install.packages("rJava", type="source)`, it comes with error:

```
make: *** [jri_glue.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have tried `sudo R CMD javareconf` and then reinstall the rJava package but it does not work. When I use `sudo R CMD javareconf` on terminal, it shows that

```
ava interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 13.0.2
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/darwin
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
gcc-7 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
gcc-7 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server -ljvm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation


JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/darwin
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.
```

This problem happened before and I use this solution [trouble installing and loading rJava on mac El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081227/trouble-installing-and-loading-rjava-on-mac-el-capitan). But when my mac is updated to Catalina 10.15.1, the solution does not work. I am not familiar with java. How to install rJava successfully in such situation?

Comment: http://www.owsiak.org/r-java-11-and-making-sure-you-can-load-rjava/