# r - Install rJava on macOS High Sierra with Java 9

Tags: java, r, gcc, homebrew, rjava

I'm looking to install the `rJava` package on macOS High Sierra with Java 9. The steps I'm following are:

1. Installed Apple Java 6
2. Installed Java 9 from Oracle
3. Terminal command: `sudo R CMD javareconf`
4. Attempted to install rJava from source with terminal command: `unset JAVA_HOME; R --quiet -e 'install.packages("rJava", type="source", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")'`

Then I got the following error:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make[2]: *** [libjri.jnilib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/JRI.jar] Error 2
make: *** [jri] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
```

I've tried following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383668/rjava-on-macos-sierra-10-12-15-unsupported-option-fopenmp) but the first command:

```
brew install homebrew/versions/gcc49 --without-multilib
```

Does not work anymore. Does anybody have a modern solution to this ever-evolving problem?

Answer (score 0):

see [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55997439/error-when-trying-to-install-rjava-from-source-on-macos-mojave/59429370#59429370)
I installed llvm with brew and got version 9 to High Sierra's version 10 from Apple. rJava then installed using:

```
 install.packages("rJava",,"http://rforge.net")
```

as noted on the [github page](https://github.com/s-u/rJava).